# Fastest way to get attribute value of custom product attribute by attribute_code and sku

Tags: magento2, product, database, attributes, performance

Hello fellow Magento developers,

What is the most efficient way of getting an attribute value of a custom eav product attribute, by only using its *attribute_code* and the products *sku*?

=> The question mainly targets the most efficient way, but answers with maintainability in mind (i.e. readable, more update secure abstractions etc.) would be great!

### Background:

The objective is to hook into the method of a PIM connector module via a plugin (interceptor), that is responsible for pushing several hundreds of products into the Magento 2 database. The plugins function itself is not relevant, however it has to run checks on every product by getting the products attribute value (product: by given sku; attribute: by given attribute_code).

The PIM connector module works like this:

1. handling data for several products in batch (~100 products per batch)
2. pushing the data from 1.) product entities as well as their attributes into the database (more or less directly: "simplified explanation").

The plugin hooks into the step 1.) and iterates over all 100 products of the batch and needs for every product as product sku i.e. 'STRING_SKU_HERE' the attribute value with attribute_code 'MY_ATTRIBUTE_CODE'.

Because the procedure may apply for thousands of products, it is **important** that the plugin and custom logic does not significally slow down the process.

### Previous attempts:

Although it is not representative, we have counted the time for fetching the needed data by using several different options.

1. try: using ProductCollection and raw SQL

```php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection */
$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();

$collection
    ->getConnection()
    ->query(
        "SELECT e.sku, e.entity_id, e.attribute_set_id, sub.*
            FROM
                `catalog_product_entity` e
            JOIN
                (
                    SELECT row_id, value_id, value
                    FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` enityvarchar
                    WHERE enityvarchar.attribute_id = (
                        SELECT attribute_id
                        FROM `eav_attribute`
                        WHERE `attribute_code` = 'MY_ATTRIBUTE_CODE'
                    )
                ) sub
                ON (e.entity_id = sub.row_id)
                WHERE sub.value IS NOT NULL AND e.sku = 'STRING_SKU_HERE'"
        )
        ->fetch();
```

**=> Time consumed: float(0.00023388862609863)**

- (+ +) time
- (- -) maintainability

2. try : pure ProductCollection

```php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection */
$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();

$collection
    ->addAttributeToSelect('STRING_SKU_HERE')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', ['STRING_SKU_HERE'])
    ->getFirstItem()
    ->getData('MY_ATTRIBUTE_CODE');
```

**=> Time consumed: float(0.0028450489044189)**

- (+) time (~10 times slower than 1.) )
- (+) maintainability
- (-) unnecessary product instantiation

3. try: via ProductResource

```php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
$product = $this->productFactory->create();

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $productResource */
$productResource = $product->getResource(); 

$productId = $productResource->getIdBySku('STRING_SKU_HERE');
$productResource->load($product, $productId, ['MY_ATTRIBUTE_CODE']);
$product->getData('MY_ATTRIBUTE_CODE');
```

**=> Time consumed: float(0.0058329105377197)**

- (+) maintainability
- (-) unnecessary product instantiation
- (-) time (not very fast, but also not very slow)

4. try: via ProductRepository

```php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository */
$productRepository = $this->productRepository;

$product = $productRepository->get('STRING_SKU_HERE');
$product->getData('MY_ATTRIBUTE_CODE');
```

**=> Time consumed: float(0.44260311126709)**

- (++) maintainability
- (-) unnecessary product instantiation
- (--) time (~ very very slow compared to 1.), 2.) 3.) )

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
Current test 2022-07-11 including variants of comments below (results vary of course (!) , they are *not representative but indicators of the time consumption* on my machine):

- Variant 1 (original question): float(0.00022697448730469)
- Variant 2 (original question): float(0.0026819705963135)
- Variant 3 (original question): float(0.040131092071533)
- Variant 4 (original question): float(0.027424097061157)
- Variant 5 (1. variant by @victor-tihonchuk): float(0.00026488304138184)
- Variant 6 (2. variant by @victor-tihonchuk): float(0.0004880428314209)

I'm curious about more opportunities. :)

Comment: In this case (edit 2022-07-11) *variant 1* faster than *Variant 5* **only** because the system doesn't spend time to work with Select instance and you don't have anything like quote or assemble query. MySQL query time in *variant 1* **slower** than *variant 5*. I made some cyclic test and can confirm that **PLAIN** hardcoded select like in `variant 1` faster than dynamic one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best one and correct is using following logic:

```php
// better to initialize all related instances in __constructor
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$eavConfig     = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Eav\Model\Config::class);
$resource      = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product::class);
$metadata      = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool::class)
    ->getMetadata(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface::class);
$linkField     = $metadata->getLinkField();
$attribute     = $eavConfig->getAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, '{ATTRIBUTE_CODE}');

$select = $resource->getConnection()->select()
    ->from(['e' => $resource->getEntityTable()], null)
    ->join(
        ['ev' => $attribute->getBackendTable()],
        sprintf(
            'e.%1$s = ev.row_id AND ev.store_id = 0 AND ev.attribute_id = %2$s',
            $linkField,
            $attribute->getAttributeId()
        ),
        'value'
    )
    ->where('e.sku = ?', '{SKU}');
$value = $resource->getConnection()->fetchOne($select);

// you can select and fetch more data if needed also check if attribute can have store value, etc
// of course this applicable only for non static attributes and you need to 
// check if your attribute is not static and implement static logic if needed
```

MySQL EXPLAIN:
[image]

Compare with your first point:
[image]

Also you have a mistake with mapping entity value `row_id`

Instead of variant 3 you can compare with:

```php
$value = $resource->getAttributeRawValue($resource->getIdBySku('{SKU}'), 'ATTRIBUTE_CODE', 0);
```

**[UPDATE]**

If you are care about performance, i've little bit improved 1st one solution and decorated with Resource Model

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Model/ResourceModel/Catalog/Product/Attribute.php`

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute as CatalogAttribute;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config as EavConfig;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityMetadataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context;

class Attribute extends AbstractDb
{
    protected EavConfig               $eavConfig;
    protected EntityMetadataInterface $metadata;

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        EavConfig $eavConfig,
        MetadataPool $metadataPool,
        $connectionName = null
    ) {
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->metadata  = $metadataPool->getMetadata(ProductInterface::class);

        parent::__construct($context, $connectionName);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('catalog_product_entity', 'entity_id');
    }

    public function getValueBySku(string $sku, string $attributeCode, int $storeId = null): ?string
    {
        /** @var CatalogAttribute $attribute */
        $attribute  = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode);
        $connection = $this->getConnection();

        $select = $connection->select()
            ->from(['e' => $this->getMainTable()], null)
            ->where('e.sku = :sku');
        $bind = [
            ':sku' => $sku,
        ];

        if ($attribute->isStatic()) {
            $select->columns($attribute->getAttributeCode(), 'e');
        } else {
            $linkField = $this->metadata->getLinkField();
            $select->join(
                ['vd' => $attribute->getBackendTable()],
                sprintf('e.%s = vd.row_id AND vd.store_id = 0 AND vd.attribute_id = :attribute_id', $linkField),
                []
            );

            $bind[':attribute_id'] = (int)$attribute->getAttributeId();

            if ($attribute->isScopeGlobal() || $storeId === null || $storeId === 0) {
                $select->columns('value', 'vd');
            } else {
                $select->joinLeft(
                    ['vs' => $attribute->getBackendTable()],
                    sprintf('e.%s = vs.row_id AND vs.store_id = :store_id AND vs.attribute_id = :attribute_id', $linkField),
                    [
                        'value' => $connection->getCheckSql('vs.value_id IS NULL', 'vd.value', 'vs.value'),
                    ]
                );
                $bind[':store_id'] = $storeId;
            }
        }

        return $connection->fetchOne($select, $bind);
    }

    public function getValueBySkuRaw(string $sku, string $attributeCode, int $storeId = null): ?string
    {
        /** @var CatalogAttribute $attribute */
        $attribute  = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode);
        $connection = $this->getConnection();

        $select  = sprintf('SELECT %%columns%% FROM %s AS e', $this->getMainTable());
        $columns = [];
        $bind = [
            ':sku' => $sku,
        ];

        if ($attribute->isStatic()) {
            $columns[] = 'e.' . $attribute->getAttributeCode();
        } else {
            $linkField = $this->metadata->getLinkField();
            $select .= sprintf(
                ' INNER JOIN %s AS vd ON e.%s = vd.row_id AND vd.store_id = 0 AND vd.attribute_id = :attribute_id',
                $attribute->getBackendTable(),
                $linkField
            );

            $bind[':attribute_id'] = (int)$attribute->getAttributeId();

            if ($attribute->isScopeGlobal() || $storeId === null || $storeId === 0) {
                $columns[] = 'vd.value';
            } else {
                $select .= sprintf(
                    ' LEFT JOIN %s AS vs ON e.%s = vs.row_id AND vs.store_id = :store_id AND vs.attribute_id = :attribute_id',
                    $attribute->getBackendTable(),
                    $linkField
                );
                $columns[] = $connection->getCheckSql('vs.value_id IS NULL', 'vd.value', 'vs.value');

                $bind[':store_id'] = $storeId;
            }
        }
        $select .= ' WHERE e.sku = :sku';
        $select = strtr($select, ['%columns%' => implode(', ', $columns)]);

        return $connection->fetchOne($select, $bind);
    }
}
```

Using recommended way:

```
$attributeResource->getValueBySku('{SKU}', '{DYNAMIC_ATTRIBUTE}');
$attributeResource->getValueBySku('{SKU}', '{DYNAMIC_ATTRIBUTE}', {STORE_ID});
$attributeResource->getValueBySku('{SKU}', '{STATIC_ATTRIBUTE}');
```

Using performance optimized way:

```
$attributeResource->getValueBySku('{SKU}', '{DYNAMIC_ATTRIBUTE}');
```

**Speed Tests (100 random SKUs)**

```
Test Result Variant #1 (from question)
Min: 0.00024199485778809
Max: 0.001270055770874
Avg: 0.00029866647720337

Test Result Variant #2 (getValueBySku)
Min: 0.00034093856811523
Max: 0.00078010559082031
Avg: 0.00038370656967163

Test Result Variant #3 (getValueBySkuRaw)
Min: 0.00019192695617676
Max: 0.00078105926513672
Avg: 0.00026803112030029

Test Result Variant #4 (plain SQL from 2/3 without placeholders and quote(sku))
Min: 0.00018095970153809
Max: 0.00065398216247559
Avg: 0.00023439168930054
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions @victor-tihonchuk.

Comparing it to the other methods, it seems like your first mentioned method is about as fast as my variant 1, while using abstractions (which is of course better). I really like your second variant and haven figured that one out before ( O_o). Right now it looks like its a very nice solution for most "generic" use cases. 
In my specific use case the first suggestion seems suitable for now.

Comment: See **[UPDATE]** section in answer. This is maintainable and fast. It should be faster in cycle with hundred products